# ScalaDocs tags in InitelliJ?

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

When I type out a method with parameters in IntelliJ then try to add doc tags to it, when I type

/**

I would expect that the @param and @return tags are filled out for me. How can I get that to automatically happen when I type the above

e.g.

```
   /**
      *
      * @param field1
      * @return String
      */      
    def testMethod(field1:String): String = "hi"
```

but instead when I do that it does this:

```
 /**
*/
    def testMethod(field1:String): String = "hi"
```

Comment: This is working for me in IntelliJ 11 CE.  Which version of IntelliJ are you using?

Comment: I'm using 11.1.2 and the latest v-0.5.800 scala plugin

Answer (score 2):

It is working in IntelliJ idea v11.1.2 and scala pluggin v0.5.800

Just type `/**` and then press "return" on top of a function. It generates the following code:

```
/**
  *
  * @param field1
  * @return
  */      
def testMethod(field1:String): String = "hi"
```

You can also try to update your scala pluggin, this feature is young.

**Edit**: There is an open ticket in JetBrains for the doc, but "it seems to be fixed"

http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/SCL-2433#tab=Comments

Comment: I'm using 11.1.2 and the latest v-0.5.800 scala plugin, which prompted my question... is there a setting that enables it somewhere? because it doesn't seem to work

Comment: I don't think so, do you enable the scala pluggin for your project?

Answer (score 0):

Must have been a problem with my existing settings somewhere, I cleared out my settings on OSX deleting the ~/Library/Preferences/IntelliJ* folder and starting it back up, reconfiguring my IntelliJ setup. It's now working with scaladoc tags now.